# Arithmetic Sequences; Finding a term given it's value.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I must have missed this topic in my notes but my assignment is asking me to find which term has a value of 38 in the arithmetic sequence of 4, 5.7, 7.4, and I do not know the formula or method of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

To find any term of an arithmetic sequence:

$$a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$$

where $a_1$ is the first term of the sequence and $d$ is the common difference , $n$ is the number of the term to find.

Comment: You know, this should have came to mind but I guess I just wasn't thinking clear.